# how to track app crash in iPhone?

Tags: ios

in iphone application developing some time app crash,in log it didn't show proper message.so my question is that,how to track right app crash reason in the Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not giving details of any specific crash, all I can tell you is general techniques for finding common errors:

1) Turn on breakpoints for Objective-C exceptions.

2) Use @try/@catch.

3) Turn on zombies (in case it's memory-related).

4) Step through the program in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try add Zombie object to your current project.
Select Product -> Edit Schema -> Diagnostics then mark Enable Zombie object 
Make sure that you left tab selection is [Run "app name"]
This make you simply track your exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Zombie and `Add Exception Breakpoint` .

[a simple tutorial](http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/capturing-exceptions-while-debugging/)  and [This is a particular post by iOS Tutorial Team member](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can be analyze or profile your project. and by using Instrument you can find the app crasing reason.